# how can we write a metaclass which returns the original object un-touched instead of calling the copy constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, metaclass

I tend to write a lot of functions which convert input arguments into instances of a user-defined class.

```py
class Klaus:
    def __init__(*args):
        pass

def fnctn(arg:Klaus):
    arg = Klaus(arg)
    print(arg)
```

For example, you might have a `Matrix` class.

We can convert lists of lists into a `Matrix`.

However, if the input to a function is already a `Matrix` then there is no need to convert the `Matrix` into a copy of the `Matrix`

We could do something like the following:

```py
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def fnctn(arg:object):
    raise NotImplementedError()

@fnctn.register
def fnctn(arg:Klaus):
    print("arg is a `Klaus`", arg)

@fnctn.register
def fnctn(arg:int):
    print("arg is an `int`. We will convert the arg into a `Klaus`")
    arg = Klaus(arg)
    return fnctn(arg)
```

However, I am curious about meta-classes.

Is it possible to define a meta-class `MetaKlaus` such that `MetaKlaus.__call__(obj)` returns `obj` un-touched? Instead of calling a copy-constructor, we just get the original object back?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might work:

```py
class BaseStrippedString:
    pass

class MetaStrippedString(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 1 and len(kwargs.keys()) == 0:
            if isinstance(args[0], BaseStrippedString):
                return args[0]
        obj = super(MetaStrippedString, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj

class StrippedString(BaseStrippedString, metaclass=MetaStrippedString):
    def __init__(self, other):
        self._myValue = str(other)
    def strip(self):
        return self
    def __getattr__(self, attrname:str):
        return getattr(self._myValue, attrname)
        


s = "   yo!\n"
ts1 = StrippedString("yo!")
ts2 = StrippedString(ts1)
print(ts1)
```